# How to freeze the table header and left column without flickering the border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on the table data. I fixed the table header and left column using jQuery. It works fine but When I am scrolling the table the border is flickering. If we apply the background color is white then the border is hidden. How can we stop the flickering the borders while scrolling the table. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here my code in JSfiddle `https: //jsfiddle.net/j41acpmx/65/`

Comment: Don't post your URL as code just to get around the requirements that links to JS Fiddle must have code in the question; instead: [edit] your question to add your "**[MCVE]**" code *to the question*. Linking to a live demo is very useful, so thank you, but your code must be in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the relative position and the border is left behind making to flicker. Two ways to solve this matter.

**First way** is with CSS and remove table's th border from the beginning and make th background white for better visibility.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfysr0be/

**Second way** is to subtract the border width when positioning the fixed th elements.

Your current border is 2px so, I subtracted 2px from css top property at line 115. This will push th 2 pixels up.

```
if(settings.head)
            {
                this.find("thead tr > *").css("top", parseInt(top)-2);
                ...
            }
```

Comment: Hi..I have already tried those two methods. I need the table border should be shown including outline also while scrolling the table. The problem is the relative position of the header. Is there any alternative way to solve this.. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can also change your CSS to this.
Adding box inset shadows to th to solve with 2 pixels missing when floating.

```
 #parent {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }
 .table{
        border-collapse: collapse;

        }
  td{
     border-top: 2px solid;
     background: white;
     padding: 5px;
    }
  th{
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
```

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/af2quek5/

Comment: If you want both top and bottom borders for your thead while scrolling, you probably might want to think of adding <span> tag inside th and style the borders.